# How to start outlook minimized (vb.net)

Tags: vb.net, outlook

Following code starts excel minimized.

```
Dim psi As New ProcessStartInfo("excel.exe")
psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized
Process.Start(psi)
```

Following code starts notepad minimized.

```
Dim psi As New ProcessStartInfo("notepad.exe")
psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized
Process.Start(psi)
```

Following code **does not start** outlook minimized.

```
Dim psi As New ProcessStartInfo("outlook.exe")
psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized
Process.Start(psi)
```

**Why?**

Related link: (C#)
[How to start Outlook minimized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11763528/how-to-start-outlook-minimized)